# Sorting the order of contents in a cell

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

As the title suggests, I was wondering if it were possible to sort the order of contents with in a cell according to the text. For example, some cells that contain the text "4C + 5C + BBU/RRH + 4T4R" that have a specific complexity number associated with it. The problem is to vlookup that specific complexity number I need to have the text within the cell in that exact order for it to match. I have this jumbled order for several other iterations (e.g. "4C + 2nd RRH + 3C + BBU/RRH" should read "2C + 3C + 2nd RRH + BBU/RRH"). If given the correct order of preference if it exists in the cell would it be possible to correct the order of contents in the cell? Here is the associated preference list:

1. 2C
2. 3C
3. 4C
4. 5C
5. 6C
6. 7C
7. 2nd RRH
8. RRH ADD
9. BBU/RRH
10. XMU/RRH
11. 4T4R

Such that the cell should be able to form a ranking system of what should go first, second, third, etc. if it exists in the cell (e.g. should be able to take "7C + 3C + 4T4R + RRH ADD" into "3C + 7C + RRH ADD + 4T4R" just as "4C + 3C + 2C" should read "2C + 3C + 4C"). I'd like to be able to apply this formula over a column AU using VBA if possible. Thanks in advance, I haven't seen anything quite like this issue, so any insight would be go a long way.

Comment: What have you tried?  What does your data look like?  Why put it all in one cell when Excel excels at separating and grouping data to make it easy to handle?

Comment: @R. Roe I had tried that method of text to columns, but still was unable to get the final cell to sort them in a particular order because they weren't A->Z. Additionally, with the inclusion of + this spread across many rows for some instances and not others which also altered the order. Finally, they must all be in one cell because that specific combination that I noted is tied to a complexity number that I must extract using a vlookup and it will not vlookup correctly if the text within the cell is in a different order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the original string for the existence of the values in an ordered way and construct a new string, as below:

```
Function customSort(ByVal original As String) As String

    Dim SortBy As Variant
    Dim n As Double
    Dim strReturn As String

    SortBy = Array("2C", _
                   "3C", _
                   "4C", _
                   "5C", _
                   "6C", _
                   "7C", _
                   "2nd RRH", _
                   "RRH ADD", _
                   "BBU/RRH", _
                   "XMU/RRH", _
                   "4T4R")


    'for each in SortBy array
    For n = 0 To UBound(SortBy)
        'loop from 1 to count of occurrence in string
        '(Len(original) - Len(Replace$(original, SortBy(n), ""))) / Len(SortBy(n)) counts occurrences in string, case sensitive
        For i = 1 To (Len(original) - Len(Replace$(original, SortBy(n), ""))) / Len(SortBy(n))
            strReturn = strReturn & SortBy(n) & " + "
        Next
    Next

    customSort = Left(strReturn, Len(strReturn) - 3)

End Function
```

You can either call this function from a `Sub` or use it as a `cell formula`.

`e.g.: =customSort(A2)`

Comment: I'm having some trouble implementing this function due to the keywords SortBy and UBound. I thought SortBy and UBound were meant to be a placeholder for me to dimensionalize. E.g. I tried to dimension SortBy As Double and LastRow As Long that finds the lastrow of the sheet but instead it is expecting an array. I'm unsure how to fix these problems to see if the function works.

Comment: You shouldn't need to change anything in the function for it to work, `SortBy` is an array containing the `Keywords` and `Order` that you want to sort your strings by. `Ubound` is the size of the `SortBy` array. If you tell me what are you trying to do with the `function` I'll edit my answer with it. BTW did you try using the function straight as a cell formula/UDF (`e.g.: =customSort(AU2)`)?

Comment: Yes, I tried to input the formula outside of VBA in an adjacent column (AV) to see if it worked. I set AV2 = customSort(AT2), where AT is the column that contains the jambled text cell. It keeps telling me that there is an error - SortBy variable not defined. One other note some cells only contain one string inside them e.g. "2C" or "2nd RRH" with no " + " in them. I also tried this function in cells that only contained several strings, e.g. "6C + 4C + 5C + 4T4R"  and still received the same error.

Comment: The number of `"2C"` or `+` doesn't make a difference on the `function`. Do you have `Option Explicit` on the top of you Module? If so you'll need to `Dim` the following variables, `Dim SortBy As Variant`, 
    `Dim n As Double`,
    `Dim strReturn As String`

Comment: Ahhhh, I do in the Sub that handles merging worksheets together in a specific folder. I did not realize that had ramification in terms of executing a function, sorry for the lack of information. This works now! Thank you so much. One last request, if a duplicate were to occur in the string (e.g. if 4T4R occurs twice in the original cell) how do I get it to appear twice in the correct sorted cell? Cell "4T4R + 6C + 4T4R + 5C" should read "5C + 6C + 4T4R + 4T4R".

Comment: Just making sure you saw the end of my last comment. Tried to add another "4T4R" to the end of the array but that just added it to every instance that 4T4R occurred.

Comment: @Shin, just updated the code taking into account 2 or more repetitions.